# router links are not loading the compoenent

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-dom, react-link

```
  <div className="app">
        <Router>
          <Link
            to="/dashboard"
            style={{ width: "25rem", marginLeft: "50px", marginTop: "50px" }}>
            Passing Props
          </Link>
          <Link
            to="/"
            style={{ width: "25rem", marginLeft: "50px", marginTop: "50px" }}>
            Home
          </Link>
          <Link
            to="/signin"
            style={{ width: "25rem", marginLeft: "50px", marginTop: "50px" }}>
            signin
          </Link>
          <Link
            to="/signup"
            style={{ width: "25rem", marginLeft: "50px", marginTop: "50px" }}
          >
            signup
          </Link>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              path="/dashboard"
              component={() => <AWSConnection topic={this.state.topic} />}
            />
            <Route path="/" />
            <Route path="/signup" component={SignInForm}/>
            <Route path="/signin" component={SignUpForm}/>
          </Switch>
        </Router>

 </div>
```

only Home and dashboard are working the other two are not showing anything

my imports are

```
import {BrowserRouter  as Router, Route, Link, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
```

when i click Home it goes to home and when i click dashboard it goes to dashboard
but when i click signin or signup nothing happens. i see url change to/signin and /singup
but nothing displayed. i tested with a dummpy component insteat of signin  and singup still the same it cant load the dummpy component

Comment: The code seems fine to me. Can you check if you have imported the SignInForm and SignUpForm correctly? or can you make a sandbox where we can test your code

Answer (score 2):

Use the "exact" prop. Your router is going through all your defined routes and returning the first available match in this case "/" is the first available match for all your routes.

Comment: Thanks for the details. i changed the order and used exact

Answer (score 1):

you can either set the exact prop on the router, or can change your routes to:

```
<Switch>
  <Route 
    path="/dashboard" 
    component={() => <AWSConnection topic={this.state.topic} />}
  />
  <Route path="/signup" component={SignInForm} />
  <Route path="/signin" component={SignUpForm} />
  <Route path="/" />
</Switch>
```

The Switch component will return the first compatible route, and / is compatible with everything.

You can go [here](https://reactrouter.com/core/guides/quick-start) for the react router official docs.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "exact" prop in every Route component:

```
<Route path="/signin" exact component={SignUpForm}/>
```

Doing so, will make your Switch render only the component you want.